# How to handle data skew when working with partner portal?

Tags: sharing, customer-portal, partner-communities, apex-sharing, sharing-sets

I have a very simple use case where I have a few partner accounts to which I assign cases. Under each account I have 5-10 partner users who need access to all the cases assigned to the account. So I've set up a basic sharing by relating the case to a partner account and then sharing it with portal users using sharing sets. Now as the volume increases, I'm expecting a daily insertion of 10000-20000 case records everyday that are assigned to 2-3 of these accounts. This data is inserted using bulk api v2 so I am expecting record lock issues.

How can such a situation be handled provided I can't archive the older records in the system ?

I am thinking of adding the users under each account to a group and sharing the records with them via Apex or adding them in a queue and assigning it as the owner. How feasible is this and will this not lead to ownership based skew ?

Comment: How did you resolve this?

Comment: @PartOfTheOhana, I couldn't find any fix for this. I was left with no choice but timely archival and assigning all the records to a particular skew user once the partner users didn't require the access to the records.